# Training using pytorch Distributed Data Parallel with world_size 4 on a multi-gpu machine continues even when only two GPU processes started

Tags: pytorch, distributed

I want to run a test to see how the synchronization works. I assume that at the end of each batch, DDP would wait for the processes on the world_size GPUs to reach the synchronization point like a backward pass to synchronize gradients.  I used a 4-GPU machine and use environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to make sure only 2 GPU processes can be started.  If only 2 GPU processes started, I assume that at the end of the first batch, the synchronization on the existing 2 GPUS would wait on the other two and time out as the other two never started. What I observed is that the training continued with only 2 GPU processes, even though the world size is 4. How to explain this? Is my understanding not correct?